# Instead of submit get data on entering page php

Tags: php

I use this snippet to get vehicle data from a external database:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" class="vwe-kenteken-widget">
    <p><input type="text" name="open_data_rdw_kenteken" value="<?php echo $_POST['open_data_rdw_kenteken'] ?>" maxlength="8"></p>
    <p><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="<?php _e('Kenteken opzoeken', 'open_data_rdw') ?>"></p>
</form>
<?php if($data): ?>
    <h3><?php _e('Voertuiggegevens', 'open_data_rdw') ?></h3>
    <table>
        <?php
        $categories = array();
        foreach ($data as $d) {
            if( !is_array($fields) || in_array($d['name'], $fields) ) {
                if( !in_array($d['category'], $categories) ) {
                    $categories[] = $d['category'];
                    echo '<tr class="open-rdw-header">';
                    echo '<td colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">';
                    echo '<a href="#">'.$d['category'].'</a>';
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                echo '<tr style="display:none">';
                echo '<td>'.$d['label'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$d['value'].'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What i want to accomplish is that the data is loaded without the user have to enter a value and hit the submit button. The input value will get loaded based on the product page the user is viewing.

EDIT:

The data is loaded based on:

```
public function get_json() {
        if ( isset( $_POST['kenteken'] ) ) {
            $data = $this->rdw->get_formatted($_POST['kenteken']);
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $json['result'][$row['name']] = $row['value'];
            }

            if ($_POST['kenteken']) {
                if ($data[0]['value'] == '') {
                    $json['errors'] = __( 'No license plates found', 'open_data_rdw' );
                }
                else {
                    $json['errors'] = false;
                }   
            }
            else {
                $json['errors'] = __( 'No license plate entered', 'open_data_rdw' );
            }

            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($json);
            die();
        }
    }
```

So instead of a $_POST action just get the data based on a pre-declared value that is different on each page.

Comment: Where do you define $data ? So if im correct you want to autosubmit the form on page load ?

Comment: Have you tried using Ajax?

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani I edited the initial question.

Comment: @RonaldPK The way its loading right now is not the right way according to you?

Comment: So you want something like a search function without having to enter a value inside the input?

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani Its a search function now, but instead of the user entering a value i want to declare the value based on a custom value and load the data without the user clicking the submit button

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery or ajax on document ready with the posted value pass that to the get_json as a parameter

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani Well that's the thing, i have no idea how to do that in this case.

Comment: Oke first of all. Do you want the $_POST['open_data_rdw_kenteken'] to get passed to get_json. I mean does open_data_rdw_kenteken and kenteken return the same value?

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani Yes that will be a license plate entered in the backend as a custom product field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to answer - but I'll try to use my crystal ball.
*$data* comes from a database query, right?

I assume further, that the query takes the value from the *open_data_rdw_kenteken* form field to gather *$data*.

To have the table rendered, you have to fill *$data* with the right data. That implies that you must have a kind of default value for  *open_data_rdw_kenteken* to get the data out of the DB. The default can be "all" which should reflect on your SQL Query or as your wrote "defined by product page".

Pseudo Code

```
$data = getData('BT-VP-41'); 

function getData($open_data_rdw_kenteken="")
{
     $where = "";
     if(!empty($open_data_rdw_kenteken)) {
         $where = 'WHERE rdw_kenteken = "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($open_data_rdw_kenteken)';
     }
     $data = myslqi->query("SELECT * FROM dbTbl ".$where)
     return $data;
}
```

As I wrote - this is pseudo code and will not run out of the box. You'll have to adapt that to your environment.

TL;DR: The line

```
 <?php if($data): ?>
```

keeps you from rendering the table. To render you need $data filled with the right data.

Hope that will get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for this! This pointed me in the right direction. I just loaded $data with <?php $data = $this->rdw->get_formatted('CUSTOMFIELDVALUE'); ?> and it worked perfectly. Thanks again!